# Retrieve more information from PFUser pointers using joint class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

I have `Project`, `User` and joint class `ProjectEmployee`. `ProjectEmployee` contains pointers to a `Project` and to a `User`. I will skip other params as they unneeded for this example.

When I do employee fetch it returns for me only pointers. Which looks like ok for performance.

This is how I save `ProjectEmployee`

```
let parseObject = PFObject(className:"ProjectEmployee")

parseObject["active"] = true
parseObject["user"] = pfUser
parseObject["project"] = pfProject
parseObject["occupation"] = pfOccupation
            
parseObject.saveInBackground
```

My question how can I get `ProjectEmployee` with more information. For now I just see pointers when I do fetch from backend database. Which is correct, but I need more information about `User` and `Project`.

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"ProjectEmployee")
query.findObjectsInBackground
```

For example I need to get username of `User` and etc.

The main issue I am trying to solve is to filter a list of user which are in the project already but using joint class.

When I am on the project details screen I show all `User` records in table view. I select the users and as I have `Project` object and array or User objects I create joint class ProjectEmployee. But next time I open project details screen I want to show all `User` records excluding the users I already added to a `Project`

I guess the question could be separated to two subquestion.

1. Do I need to fetch pointers info via additional query, if so how to do it right.
2. Do I need to use joint class for this purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of relational queries at Parse:
http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relational-queries

Comment: yea thanks! looks like this is what I need. Answering my question number 1. I just need includeKey option. I supposed I need another query fortunately I was wrong. 2. I need joint class as well.